# SceneDelegate - DynamicLink getInitialLink() and onLink() don't work on iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native

Description

Recently in one of my projects I correctly integrated the dynamicLinks with getInitialLink() and onLink() APIs.

However out of necessity I had to modify AppDelegate.m and introduce AppDelegate.swift handling (+ adding a SceneDelegate).

There are two scenes **PhoneScene** and **CarPlayScene**, this was necessary for the introduction of CarPlay within the project.

Since I made these changes on the native side, the functions related to Linking have stopped working completely, always returning null.

What we have been able to understand is that with the introduction from iOS 13 of SceneDelegates the initial app launch parameters (launchOptions in iOS) and subsequent calls from background mode are no longer handled by **AppDelegate.swift** but by **SceneDelegate**. In our case in **PhoneScene.swift**.

#### Expected Behavior

1. uninstall app -> click dynamic link -> install app -> open app -> *Firebase read dynamic link URL from Clipboard* -> deep link invoked getInitialURL() API -> URL
2. terminate app -> click dynamic link -> open app -> deep link invoked getInitialURL() API -> URL
3. background mode -> click dynamic link -> open app -> deep link invoked onLink() API -> URL

#### Version

0.68.2

Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.6.5
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Memory: 79.48 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.19.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.16 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.0.1, iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744
    Xcode: 13.1/13A1030d - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 =17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.68.2 =0.68.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Steps to reproduce

#### 1. Remove previous ObjC files

- Delete `main.m`
- Delete `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.mm`

#### 2. Create the new Swift AppDelegate

Create a new `AppDelegate.swift` file, once prompted, click *Create bridging headers for Swift*.

Paste the following code to the `AppDelegate.swift`, it includes Flipper code.

```
// ios/AppDelegate.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CarPlay
import React
#if DEBUG
#if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
import FlipperKit
#endif
#endif

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge?;
  var rootView: RCTRootView?;
  static var shared: AppDelegate { return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate }

  func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -URL! {
    #if DEBUG
    return RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackURLProvider:nil);
    #else
    return Bundle.main.url(forResource:"main", withExtension:"jsbundle")
     #endif
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -Bool {
    initializeFlipper(with: application)
    print("launchOptions", launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url])
    self.bridge = RCTBridge.init(delegate: self, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    self.rootView = RCTRootView.init(bridge: self.bridge!, moduleName: "PROJECT_NAME", initialProperties: nil)
    
    RNBootSplash.initWithStoryboard("BootSplash", rootView: rootView);
    
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    print("connectionScene")
    if (connectingSceneSession.role == UISceneSession.Role.carTemplateApplication) {
      let scene =  UISceneConfiguration(name: "CarPlay", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
      scene.delegateClass = CarSceneDelegate.self
      return scene
    } else {
      let scene =  UISceneConfiguration(name: "Phone", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
      scene.delegateClass = PhoneSceneDelegate.self
      return scene
    }
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
  }

  private func initializeFlipper(with application: UIApplication) {
    #if DEBUG
    #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
    let client = FlipperClient.shared()
    let layoutDescriptorMapper = SKDescriptorMapper(defaults: ())
    client?.add(FlipperKitLayoutPlugin(rootNode: application, with: layoutDescriptorMapper!))
    client?.add(FKUserDefaultsPlugin(suiteName: nil))
    client?.add(FlipperKitReactPlugin())
    client?.add(FlipperKitNetworkPlugin(networkAdapter: SKIOSNetworkAdapter()))
    client?.start()
    #endif
    #endif
  }
}
```

Paste the following to your bridging header file `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import "RNCarPlay.h"
#import "RNBootSplash.h"
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#endif
#endif
```

3. Add flags for Swift compiler in debug mode

Go to XCode project, hit `Build Settings`, search for `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags` and then under `Active Compilation Conditions`, add the following flags to `Debug` only:

- DEBUG
- FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED

#### 4. Create Phone Scene

Add a new Swift file called `PhoneScene.swift`:

```
// ios/PhoneScene.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
class PhoneSceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) else { return }
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = appDelegate.rootView;
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
}
```

5. Create Car Scene

Add a new Swift file called `CarScene.swift`

```
// ios/CarScene.swift
import Foundation
import CarPlay
class CarSceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
  func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                                  didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    RNCarPlay.connect(with: interfaceController, window: templateApplicationScene.carWindow);
  }
  func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didDisconnectInterfaceController interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    RNCarPlay.disconnect()
  }
}
```

6. Update the manifest in Info.plist

Add the following ApplicationScene manifest to your `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>CarPlay</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarSceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>UIWindowScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Phone</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).PhoneSceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository

#### Implement all delegates in AppDelegate and PhoneScene to capture URLs in the following cases:

1. uninstall app -click deep link -install app -open app
2. terminate app -click deep link. -open app
3. background mode -click deep link -open app

#### `PhoneScene.swift`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    //...
    
    // <---- either one will work ---->
    print("connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url", connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url)
    print("connectionOptions.userActivities.first?.webpageURL", connectionOptions.userActivities.first?.webpageURL)
  }
  
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    // <---- first launch after install ---->
    print("URLContexts", URLContexts.first?.url)
  }

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    // <---- when in background mode ---->
    print("userActivity", userActivity.webpageURL)
  }
```

```
AppDelegate.swift
// ios/AppDelegate.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CarPlay
import React
#if DEBUG
#if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
import FlipperKit
#endif
#endif

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate {
 // ...

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
   restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -Void) -> Bool {
    print("userActivity.webpageURL", userActivity.webpageURL)
    return true;
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool{
    // <---- first launch after install ---->
    print("first launch after install", url)
    return true;
  }
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool{
    // <---- first launch after install for older iOS version ---->
    print("first launch after install for older iOS version", url)
    return true;
  }

}
```

now linking returns null every time it is invoked.